# Help translating 针一的材质

Tags: translation

Please help translating the following phrase:

> 针一的材质

Does it mean "first class material"?

Comment: Can you provide picture or link to the original phrase? That doesn't look Chinese to me.

Comment: Original sentence.
价格方面今天跟厂家确认过了，之前给你打样品过去用的是针一的材质。原先我们用的是针二的材质。

Comment: "针一", based on the context, it is probably just a (not so important) jargon used in a specific company or industry.  I think, it describes the quality of some material, I guess the material is "针" needle, and “一” can mean first class or category one

Comment: No, we don't anything with needles. Thank you very much for your comment. Yeah, jargon what matters, I have already felt it working almost a year with my colleagues from Wenzhou.

Comment: What a coincidence, I am Wenzhounese (now in New York)

Comment: OMG! Why do people from Wenzhou speak that fast? And they are the reason why I am here! :) Cause I get frustrated with my Chinese knowledge!

Comment: I think your frustration might caused by the fact that, the older generation Wenzhounese is more comfortable with  their dialect (namely wenzhounese) than standard chinese (Mandarin) due to some historical issue in recent history

Comment: The people I speak with are 30-50 year old engineers and accountants. And the way they speak is far too different I got used to hear in Chinese soap operas :)

Comment: No, it does not mean "first class material". Are you buying some kind of fabric material or glasses cleaning cloth?

针一, 针二 often used in microfiber

1.针一 200g/cm³ microfiber；
2.针二 180g/cm³ microfiber；
3.针三 150g/cm³ microfiber。

Comment: Thank you very much Sean. That is what I was looking for. Microfiber!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`针一` and `针二` are just names of materials. They refer to different kinds of cloth. (Those words are quite professional. Even native speakers don't know that.)